# JFlex parametrized token

Tags: jflex

I want to parse expressions of the following structure:

```
compositeKey ::= key (separator key)*
```

Here is the flex code fragment:

```
KEY_CHARACTER=[^:\s]
KEY_SEPARATOR=[:]

%state WAITING_KEY

...
<WAITING_KEY> {KEY_CHARACTER}+        { yybegin(WAITING_KEY); return MyTypes.KEY; }
<WAITING_KEY> {KEY_SEPARATOR}         { yybegin(WAITING_KEY); return MyTypes.KEY_SEPARATOR; }
```

Code generated by given flex fragment works fine, but what if I want to get key separator at "runtime"?
It actually may be any character, specified by user. 
How to do it with jflex?